# SetWindowsHookExA не отображается в IDA Pro

Tags: c++, winapi, ida-pro

День добрый. Никогда ранее я не занимался реверсом приложений.
И как понятно, я не использовал IDA Pro. Сегодня появилась такая нужда.
Дело в том, что приложение использует для бинда те кнопки, которые отсутствуют на моей клавиатуре, в следствии мне нужно их изменить. Собрана программа под С++.
Проблема в том, что во вкладке Imports я вижу функции, которые использует приложение. Все, кроме одной. А именно: SetWindowsHookExA(и все остальные ей вызываемые тоже не показываются). Если подключить к программе Blade API Monitor то можно увидеть, как функция вызывается два раза. По логике приложения так и должно быть:

[image: скриншот вызова setwindowshookexa]

В IDA Pro же нет такой функции. Мне нужно изменить ее параметр на другой, подскажите, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение найдено.
Кнопки перехватывались при помощи GetAsyncKeyState, которая нашлась в IDA Pro. 
**Вопрос закрыт.**

[image: blade api monitor]
[image: ida pro]

Comment: Ваш случай очень часный. Не имея программу и IDA мы врядли бы откопали результат. Очень хорошо что вы получили результат. Я разбирал delphi-програму IDA и даже взломал. Незнаю пригодится ли эта информация другим, если вы считаете что да, поставьте зеленую галочку, тогда вопрос не будет среди неотвеченых. Если нет - можно удалить ответ:)

Comment: Могу только отметить только завтра